# Height and min-height is not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have my 3d design working perfectly as expected in chrome, but not in Firefox!!!

The thing is, I have an empty image tag and I need to fill it, so I tried to  give it a min-height, but it's not working.

Moreover, if I tried to use fixed height, it doesn't work either!!! I have seen other solutions, the only thing that worked with me is display:block, but this raise more issues than it solves, as it doesn't display my CSS as intended and if I tried to adjust it in Firefox, it screw my chrome design, also I tried `overflow :hidden`, but it doesn't work either

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
       <img />
   </div>
  </li>
</ul>

li {display:inline; float:left;}
li img{width:300px;height:380px;}
```

Is there another way beside display block???

Comment: [There are plenty of ways to set `display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display?v=example)... You should read about what `inline` and `block` actually mean, and then take a look at `inline-block`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the broken image visible in Firefox with the specified width and height, you can use the `-moz-force-broken-image-icon` property.
This Mozilla specific property will have no effect in other browsers.

```css
li {
  display: inline; float: left;
}

li img {
  width: 300px; height: 380px;
  -moz-force-broken-image-icon: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div><img></div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div><img></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's how you can tell a mozillander.